# Cannot access the TextBox in MainPage.xml.cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am creating a Windows Store Blank application. Following is my code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="700"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Sample Search Application"  Margin="30" FontSize="36" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtsearch" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30" TextChanged="txtsearch_TextChanged"></TextBox>
        <Button x:Name="BtnPrint" Content="GetValue" Click="BtnPrint_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Result" FontSize="36"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

As you see that I have defined a textbox. But in the cs file I am unable to access this textblock. Following is my cs file snapshot:

[image]

Comment: did you build the project before attempting to reference txtsearch? Also, I've had similar issues to this before where this would fix itself if I shut down Visual Studio, and started it again. Does that work for you?

Comment: I assume your text box is contained inside a data-template or a control-template. that is one of the reason why you may not be able to access it. please confirm the same.

Comment: If this was merely a compilation error, can the question be closed as "not reproducible"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit F5 and try again. Maybe it is not yet compiled.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the TextBlock name,

```
<TextBlock Name="txtTest" Text="Flickr Search Application"  Margin="30" FontSize="36" />
```

**EDIT:**

Since you have TextBlock inside a parent control, you can use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Sorry, I have done a mistake. Now i have updated my question. Please check again.

Comment: i saved my application. i do not changed anything. now its done. Anyway thanks

Comment: I have already mentioned that i did not change my code. I saved my application again and its done.